# 'NSDate' may not respond to +dateWithString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate

```
NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-12-25 00:00:00 -0600"];
```

I'm getting a warning message: `NSDate` may not respond to `+dateWithString`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

maybe you mean the method in [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: I got it.    NSString *dateString = @"25-Dec-10";
 
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yy";
 
 NSDate *future = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

Answer (score 22):

NSDate dateFromString is MacOS only, not iOS.

Comment: how do you know this?  the docs i'm looking at don't even mention iOS, only OSX.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithString:

Comment: @ericsoco, try the [NSDate class ref for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Even without opening the url you can see that this doc is not for iOS. And if you look inside ... "Availability: Available in OS X v10.0 and later"